# Select row using the length of list in pandas cell

Tags: python, pandas, list, pandas-loc

I have a table df

```
    a   b    c
1   x   y   [x]

2   x   z   [c,d]

3   x   t   [e,f,g]
```

Just wondering how to select the row using the length of c column

such as

```
df.loc[len(df.c) >1]
```

I know this is not right.... what should be the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using

```
df.loc[np.array(list(map(len,df.c.values)))>1]
```

Answer (score 36):

Try this:

```
df[df.c.map(len)>1]
```

Comment: `df[df['class'].map(len) >1 ] `

Answer (score 1):

With apply:

```
df[df.c.apply(lambda x: len(x) > 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a fourth column which would contain the length of each list in column "c". Then filter out rows such that entries in the new column is greater than 1.

```
df["length"] = df["c"].apply(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
df = df.loc[df["length"], :].drop(["length"], axis=1)
```